# Make table visualization in Grafana using Prometheus's InfoMetricFamily

Tags: python, grafana, prometheus

I have following code:

```
c = InfoMetricFamily("health", "Health Monitoring")
c.add_metric(labels=name, value={"name": name, "status": status, "value": value})
```

that supply Prometheus with following metric:

```
# HELP health_info Health Monitoring
# TYPE health_info gauge
health_info{name="external",status="danger",value="N\\A"} 1.0
```

I would like to build table dashboard in Grafana where `name`, `status`, `value` will be columns. How could I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Grafana [v4.3](https://grafana.com/blog/2017/05/23/grafana-4.3-release/), the [table panel](https://grafana.com/docs/features/panels/table_panel/) supports the display of Prometheus labels.

To create the display, add a table panel in your dashboard:

1. In the `Query` tab

   1. Toggle `Instant` to True and set `Format` to `Table`; if you start by filling the query you may have a **BIG** response freezing your window
   2. Write your query in `Metrics`: in your case `health_info`
2. In the visualization Tab, you will control the columns that should appear and format their display

   1. Remove the `Time` column (unless you need it, personally I rarely do)
   2. Set the catchall rule `/.*/` to Type `Hidden`; it will hide all your columns
   3. Use `Add column style` to hide a column to display by typing then name in `Apply to columns named` (the completion works well)
   4. You can adjust name of column in `Column Header` and tune the display

**NOTE:** currently, you cannot modify the order of the columns.

If you want to display multiple metrics on the same lines note that:

- all labels must match: remove conflicting ones by apply an aggregation function
- the name of the metric is a label: you need also to get rid of `__name__` label
- When adding the second value, the name of the column of the first value changes to `Value #A` and the display needs to be adjusted