# Grafana Prometheus "Info" Metric

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Im wondering if I can use "Info" (https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#info) metric from prometheus data to display info/data in grafana.  I haven't found any meaningful examples online with regards to using that metric.  I've checked the sample dashboards but I don't see any use of that metric.  I've tried sending data to prometheus with the example in the link above:

```
from prometheus_client import Info, push_to_gateway, CollectorRegistry
regis = CollectorRegistry()
i = Info('my_build_version', 'Description of info')
i.info({'version': '1.2.3', 'buildhost': 'foo@bar'})
push_to_gateway('http://localhost:9091', job="Try_Info_metric", registry=regis)
```

Anyone have meaningful queries/visual in grafana that I can use?  Im trying to see if I can display this as a table some how.

Comment: The answer to this question may be what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627208/make-table-visualization-in-grafana-using-prometheuss-infometricfamily/58633647#58633647

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that looking into pushgateway the info metric is a gauge that has value of 1.
I suppose I can use gauge as a way to build the table with the metrics.

Answer (score 4):

I have a `build_info` metric exported by all services that looks like this:

```
build_info{commit_id="42806c2f7f1e17a63d94db9d561d220f53d38ee0",commit_time="2019-11-16 13:53:46Z",build_time="2019-11-16 13:57:20Z",branch="v19.57.x",version="19.57.3",} 1.0
```

And an availability graph on the service dashboard that shows how many instances are running as a filled area (plus lines for how many are supposed to be running, `count(up{job="$job",env="$env"})`, and the alerting thresholds; the dashboard defines `$job` and `$env` template variables) that looks like this:

[image: Availability graph]

So I'm using the `version` label (and when that's not available, e.g. for test deployments, the Git `commit_id`) as a label for the running instances count.

```
label_replace(
label_replace(
label_join(
  sum without(instance) (
    build_info{job="$job",env="$env"}      # Take labels of `build_info`
      * on(job, env, instance) group_left  # Multiplied by `up`, for the actual value
    up{job="$job",env="$env"}),
  "build", "_", "version", "commit_id"),   # Join `version` and `commit_id` label values into label `build`
"build", "$1", "build", "MASTER_(.{7}).+"),# Retain the `commit_id` if `version == "MASTER"
"build", "$1", "build", "(.+)_.+")         # Else, retain `version`
```

To end up with a metric that looks like:

```
{branch="v19.57.x",build="19.57.3",build_time="2019-11-16 14:02:38Z",commit_id="42806c2f7f1e17a63d94db9d561d220f53d38ee0",commit_time="2019-11-16 13:53:46Z",env="prod",job="foo-service",version="19.57.3"} 10
```

And finally, in the query legend format in Grafana I put `Version {{ build }}`, to end up with `Version 19.57.3` in the legend.

On the graph you will notice for example that we went from 19.57.2 to 19.58.3, but then had to roll back to 19.57.3 last evening due to a regression.

**Edit** Here's the JSON for a table panel that shows pretty much what you want. (It is based on editing in place the https://play.grafana.org/d/000000065/prometheus-console-tables?orgId=1 dashboard you provided.)

```
{
"datasource": "demo.robustperception.io",
"columns": [
  {
    "text": "Current",
    "value": "current"
  }
],
"editable": true,
"error": false,
"fontSize": "100%",
"gridPos": {
  "h": 7,
  "w": 24,
  "x": 0,
  "y": 7
},
"id": 2,
"isNew": true,
"links": [],
"pageSize": null,
"scroll": true,
"showHeader": true,
"sort": {
  "col": 0,
  "desc": true
},
"styles": [
  {
    "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
    "pattern": "Time",
    "type": "date"
  },
  {
    "alias": "up",
    "colorMode": null,
    "colors": [
      "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)",
      "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
      "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)"
    ],
    "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
    "decimals": 2,
    "pattern": "Value",
    "thresholds": [],
    "type": "number",
    "unit": "short"
  }
],
"targets": [
  {
    "expr": "sum by (job, instance, version, revision) ({__name__=~\".*_build_info\"})",
    "format": "table",
    "instant": true,
    "intervalFactor": 1,
    "refId": "A",
    "step": 30,
    "target": "",
    "hide": false,
    "legendFormat": ""
  }
],
"title": "Multiple queries merge",
"transform": "table",
"type": "table",
"options": {}
}
```

Comment: Thats very cool!  However, Im trying to make tables like this: https://play.grafana.org/d/000000065/prometheus-console-tables?orgId=1.
I realized that "info" metric is just a gauge and the 'table' view settings are little different.